# Specialising on two ancestor class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have defined an abstract interface consisting of three classes:

```
class rendering_context {…}
class window : public rendering_context {…}
class offscreen : public rendering_context {…}
```

This allows various client objects to ignore what type of rendering context they’re in. So far so good.

I then defined concrete implementations:

```
class sdl::window : public window {…}
class sdl::offscreen : public offscreen {…}
```

This all works as expected, and client classes are happy with no idea whether they are on-screen / off-screen / SDL-based or not.

*My confusion:*

I now have SDL-specific functionality which applies in all rendering contexts, i.e. not just in one or the other of `sdl::window` or `sdl::offscreen`.

This suggests a class of `sdl::rendering_context` needs to be pulled out somewhere, but how do I get this into the class hierarchy?

If I make the concrete classes like so:

```
class sdl::window : public window, public sdl::rendering_context {…}
class sdl::offscreen : public offscreen, public sdl::rendering_context {…}
```

And assuming `sdl::rendering_context` inherits from `rendering_context` then haven’t I inherited from `rendering_context` twice implicitly? Does the fact that `rendering_context`, in this case, is an abstract base class, with no members and several pure virtual functions, make this okay?

Is this the same as the diamond problem? It seems like it might be, but the difference is there’s no ambiguity about which base class method to call: they are pure virtual and it will certainly be the concrete implementation at the bottom of the hierarchy which is executed in practice.

*[N.B. None of my class declarations actually look like the above, this is just to illustrate the hierarchy. The current code compiles and works, it just duplicates some functionality.]*

Comment: Having read some advice on best practice, perhaps this is the wrong question? Should I instead re-use the `sdl::rendering_context` code via composition, and leave the class hierarchy purely for defining the interfaces?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree. Having written the question, I realise this is more about my general approach to defining the interface and reusing code, and less about the specific technical issue.

Comment: Here’s a recasting of the question on the Programmers StackExchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/246273/code-re-use-in-c-via-multiple-inheritance-or-composition-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And assuming sdl::rendering_context inherits from rendering_context then haven’t I inherited from rendering_context twice implicitly?

If this is a problem, you could consider [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance), in which `rendering_context` is a *shared* base class. If you wish to do this:

```
class window : public virtual rendering_context {...}
class offscreen : public virtual rendering_context {...}
```

Comment: Gotcha, yes this works, thanks. Do you know if there are performance implications for the virtual base class when it’s pure virtual?